# excel vba auto-generate email problems

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I would like to know what happened to my codes below.
I am trying to auto-generate emails based on a list of emails and the list can be changed. Therefore, I have to use do until loop (till range ("A" & i) is empty)
[auto generate email pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6vDH.png)

I am new to VBA and just trying to learn.

```
Sub own()
    Dim shName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 10
    Do Until Range("A" & i).Value = ""
       shName = Range("A" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shName).Copy

        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

        i = i + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

The error message is **invalid procedure call or argument**..
why? 
The expected result should be able to send out email according to the list (which can be changed and therefore do until loop is used) .

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one object `cell` in your code that needs to be `Set`.

Do you have a sheet that actually has the name of the email you are trying to send? Because that is what your code attempts to do.

I've modified your code from a `Do... Loop` to `For... Next`. It's too easy to get stuck in a endless loop withou knowing what is wrong.

Whether this code will work depends on your input variables.

```
Sub own()
    Dim shName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set cell = ActiveCell 'or whatever refrence needed

    For i = 1 To 10
    If Not (Range("A" & i).Value = "") Then
        shName = Range("A" & i).Value
        'Is there a worksheet that corresponds to the email name?
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shName).Copy
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show _
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```